# Set phpunit tag language to php

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Currently, code in questions about phpunit is not highlighted correctly because (I guess) `phpunit` tag does not have language highlighting set up.

The solution for people is to tag their questions with `php` ([case in point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072964/phpunit-throwing-capturing-and-handling-custom-exceptions)).

*Edit:* On a different note, I've read that I should be able to see what language highlighting a tag uses by reading the tag info page, but either this doesn't work anymore or maybe I don't have the right access.

Comment: Um... there's 2,044 questions tagged phpunit that aren't also tagged php as of now. At a look through, it does seem some of them could do with some highlighting in lieu of any other language and it'd be a bit chaotic to go through and edit at this point... Can't see this causing any harm, so it's changed for now, and we'll see how it goes.